# BroadCastReceiver for phone State not working when app is close for Lollipop version

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-5.0-lollipop

My Broadcast receiver for `PHONE_STATE` is working for `kitkat` and `Lollipop` version even if App is Closed but when I am using `Lollipop` version its not working when app is Closed

**Here is my Manifest file**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <receiver android:name=".BlockCallReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>



    </application>
```

Comment: Please add your broadcast receiver class

Comment: reciver Class is too long.  In reciver Class I am rejecting call automatic

Comment: did u find an answer for this

Answer (score 1):

Some new android devices have security application by default. some times these apps lock your auto-start mode can you please check in settings it may be preventing boot broadcast receiver ?

Comment: Its working properly when application is Background or foreground but when i remove my app from recent App its not working

Comment: But for kitkat And Marsh-mellow versions it working.

Comment: Please give me any suggestion.I am trying to solve this issue from last 7-8 days.

Comment: You should add permission this code, Check my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new app and try this;

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
  public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str = intent.getAction();
    if ("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE".equals(str))
        inComing(context, intent);

    if ("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL".equals(str))
        outGoing(context, intent);
  }

 private void inComing(Context context, Intent intent){
    String callState = intent.getStringExtra("state");
    if ("RINGING".equals(callState)){
        Log.i(TAG, "RINGING SENDS BUSY");
    }else if ("OFFHOOK".equals(callState)){
        Log.i(TAG, "OFFHOOK SENDS BUSY");
    }else if("IDLE".equals(callState)){
        Log.i(TAG, "IDLE SENDS AVAILABLE"); 
    }
  }

 private void trueCallerOutgoing(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
    String callState = intent.getStringExtra("state");
    if ("RINGING".equals(callState)){
            Log.i(TAG, "RINGING SENDS BUSY");
    }else if ("OFFHOOK".equals(callState)){
            Log.i(TAG, "OFFHOOK SENDS BUSY");
    }else if("IDLE".equals(callState)){
            Log.i(TAG, "IDLE SENDS AVAILABLE"); 
    }
  }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
 <receiver android:name="PhoneStateReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**And Dont forget permission**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: It's working..But when i am Closing the App is not working for Lollypop version.And it's working for other versions even if Application is Closed.

Comment: try another mobil devices.

Comment: did you check system manager apk? maybe some apk blocked your apk.

Comment: Its giving problem for Lollypop versions Only

Comment: This problem is Solved using Job Scheduling.